# Using other alphabets/writing sytems for author names

Tags: discussion

The following question

[Fractional-order Rellich–Kondrashov Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259579/fractional-order-rellich-%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%be%cc%81%d0%b2-theorem)

uses the Cyrillic alphabet to write "Kondrachov", and I wanted to know what was the policy of the website concerning this vaguely "snob" practise? Of course this is not specific to Cyrillic, and Chinese would be another good example, while I have not seen such an example yet. I think the main issue is that it might be hard to track down the real name (even if in this specific case, "Rellich" made it easy).

Comment: There is no policy that I am aware of. But with Google Translate, it's usually not really hard to get the transliteration into Roman characters. (One of our active participants signs in using his native Georgian alphabet, which I don't know, but I learned through Google that his name using the English alphabet is spelled "Mamuka Jibladze".)

Comment: Thank you Prof. Trimble. I just thought that even with Google Translate, translating Chinese or Japanese names which can have a lot of readings would be quite difficult. And for a user's name it is absolutely fine, as there is no ambiguity for references.

Comment: It would be good to know if others have had difficulties here.

Comment: it breaks the search functionality, and just for that reason is preferrably avoided (until search becomes smarter)

Comment: Very good point.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker You raise a good point I hadn't considered. To all: I think there's a good chance that the author of the linked question was just trying to be respectful to the native spelling of a mathematician, and not trying to be show-offy or snobbish. I'd be happy to go in and change the title though. The only question that remains is: should it be Kondrachov, or Kondrashov? I've seen both. The name might be Ukrainian in derivation, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: I recommend using the spelling that corresponds to whatever MathSciNet or Zentralblatt reference has.  Once one gets the right paper, one can re-romanize it as needed.  Gerhard "It's The Thought That Counts" Paseman, 2017.01.14

Comment: @ToddTrimble ---  it seems all [official transliterations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian#Transliteration_table) would give "sh" instead of "ch" for the cyrillic Ш. The "ch" is for Ч.

Comment: What is important, IMO, is to respect the standard romanization of names from cyrillic and other alphabets, and to respect the correct spelling of latin alphabet names as well. It is both for a matter of respect to the person (Lebesgue non Lebesque, Hölder non Holder, Lipschitz non Lipshits, etc), *and* for the sake of a correct and useful information.

Comment: I think it is also important to see which romanization is standard or not. For example, the Wikipedia and most textbooks I know use Kondrachov, but with the example of "Chebyshev", in French the most standard is "Tchebychev", other use "Chebyshov", etc. Furthermore, sometimes the authors do not use the standard romanization for their names, or an error in the romanization is so old that one would not risk going against it (Yosida - which would translates correctly as "Yoshida" in the standard Hepburn system - is a good example).

Comment: The spelling of the Russian name in the question is inappropriate anyway. The accute accent over o is a stress mark that is *not* used in regular Russian text, only in dictionary or encyclopedia lemmata, language textbooks, and similar contexts. It's as if someone spelled an English name with syllabification dashes, as many dictionaries do.

Comment: I made an edit and (maybe temporarily) put in 'Kondrashov'. Paul-Benjamin may be right though that the spelling that appears standard in the literature is the one we should use. (This reminds me a lot of the Neumark/Naimark discussion that we had once, an instance of which is here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25878/relevance-of-the-complex-structure-of-a-function-algebra-for-capturing-the-topolo/25895#25895. Dmitri Pavlov's point largely hinged on which spelling was used by the author himself in non-Russian journals.)

Comment: @Paul-Benjamin I would not call Yosida an error in romanisation. In the Gojūon, the "table of fifty sounds", し, or "shi", is placed in the I-column on the S-row. There are multiple ways to romanise Japanese, each with their benefits and downsides. One that turns 吉田 into Yosida is not ideal for English speakers that lack an understanding of the Japanese language. It's rather systematic, however. The advantage of such a system is: Both おう and おお are pronounced as a long "o" in Japanese. But if you transcribe them as ō, you lose information that would help a Japanese person understand a sentence.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thank you for pointing that out. I took the original spelling from a dictionary indeed since I don't speak Russian myself. The transcription I'm most familiar with for the author's name is Kondrachov, which I did not want to use because it suggests an incorrect pronunciation (indeed, most of my collegues pronounce his name incorrectly). Maybe there's a good reason to use that spelling anyway. Kondrashov is rather non-standard, I think, and I did not want to start a debate (that certainly backfired) and so I left his name un-transcribed.

Comment: @anonymous I still think that Yosida is at least confusing, as in most Latin languages (and German also), the [ʃi] would be pronounced as something close to [zi], while [shi] would be closer to the correct pronunciation

Comment: @Paul-Benjamin Oh, I agree completely. I've come across many that end up mispronouncing his name as a result of the "Yosida" transcription. But as I tried to motivate in my comment above, aiding pronunciation is not the sole purpose of transcription, although for languages whose writing system is closer to English these separate features are not as distinguished.

Comment: It's worth noting that not everybody has a MathSciNet subscription to check on standard conversions to the Latin alphabet for authors (which may differ from what is 'correct' outside of mathematics)

Comment: From Donald Knuth (http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/news.html): "Later, when I typeset the index to the second edition of Volume 2, using an early prototype of TeX in 1980, I had the ability to include Chinese and Japanese names in their native form. And by the time the third editions came out in the 1990s, I was also able use Greek, Hebrew, and Cyrillic alphabets, and to present Arabic and Indian names in appropriate native scripts. At last I did not have to rely entirely on transliteration when listing the name of the father of algorithms, Abu Ja‘far Mohammed ibn Mūsā al-Khowārizmī...

Comment: "...I even hand-crafted an ancient Sumerian name by using METAFONT to draw the necessary characters of a cuneiform alphabet. 

Over the years, many people have told me how they've greatly appreciated this feature of my books. It has turned out to be a beautiful way to relish the fact that computer science is the result of thousands of individual contributions from people with a huge variety of cultural backgrounds."

Comment: I find it bizarre that the OP calls the transliteration of the name (more precisely, one transliteration of the name) 'the real name'.

Comment: Of course it is easier to misinterpret a text than trying to understand what is beyond the literal meaning of words. I did not write a mathematical theorem, and 'real name' could be easily understood of 'a name transliteration which would indicate without ambiguity the real identity of the person in question'.

Comment: @HJRW How about "generally more familiar name"? I'm not sure what the exact phrase should be -- any suggestions? Anyway, if we take English to be the scientific *lingua franca*, then something like this is surely what Paul-Benjamin intended (right, Paul-Benjamin?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the argument could be made that using such characters is a practice counter to the vague "snobbish" practice of this forum to insist on being primarily English based while intending to serve all of the research mathematical community, many of whom do not have English as a first or second language.

Switching from destructive to constructive mode, I think it is reasonable and well within forum policy to request an edit (which you can submit and someone can approve) to include in parentheses a searchable romanization.  I imagine a good policy for this forum is to tolerate, persuade, and correct, rather than to police and enforce.

Gerhard "Values Greatly Depend On Perspective" Paseman, 2017.01.14.

Comment: Thank you very much Prof. Paseman. By policy, I did not mean any interdiction, and the first statement raises a point I can only agree with, as English is my third language.

Comment: I should work on more constructive ways to deal with things that bother me.  Thank you for tolerating my response.  And you are welcome to call me Gerhard.  Gerhard "Still Enjoying His Amateur Status" Paseman, 2017.01.14.

Comment: I also think that writing an authors name in the original alphabet (additionally to her/his English latinized form) disambiguates the sometimes existing plethora of unofficial regional translations (in Germany one has Tschebyscheff and Tschebyschow, while English speakers know him as Chebyshev). So a name additionally written in its original alphabet is also some kind of respect for that person (IMHO).

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it is worth pointing out that various people might use various [transliterations of surnames from Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian).

This can be seen already in this case. You can see that Wikipedia article on [Rellich–Kondrachov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem) transcribes Кондрашов as *Kondrachov* in the title, but it says that it is named after Russian mathematician *Kondrashov*. And you can find articles using both [Kondrachov](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Rellich+Kondrachov) and [Kondrashov](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Rellich+Kondrashov).

As you can see from the long list [given here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8698/searching-for-accented-characters-is-too-strict/8709#8709), this is not the only case. (For example, there are many different spellings of Tychonoff or Chebyshev.) This is not the case only for Russian names. German names containing [scharfes S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) or [umlauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)) might appear with different transcriptions, too. (For example, Kaehler, Weierstraß.)

Therefore I think that mentioning that there are several possible transliterations might be useful for users who want to find more about the topic of the post. Adding the original Cyrillic name might be useful, too. But this should be done *in addition to* the English transliteration, since that is what typically people would use when searching using the internal SE search engine.

Comment: Only now I noticed that before I posted the answer, the OP [already explained in a comment](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3104/using-other-alphabets-writing-sytems-for-author-names#comment13875_3104) what was their rationale for using Cyrillic. This makes some parts of my answer a bit redundant, but probably there is no harm if I leave it here.

Comment: For the record, the "ch" for ш is French convention.  As explained in the linked Wikipedia article, this was the norm e.g. for passports until 1997, and would hence tend to be "the official" transliteration for anyone who is old enough to have had their passport issued then.